# How to set this to be fixed after scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, sass

I want to make this `navbar` fixed and transparent (black) and `color` to be white all that after scrolling down.

```js
let scrollpos = window.scrollY
const header = document.querySelector("navbar")
const header_height = header.offsetHeight

const add_class_on_scroll = () = \ > header.classList.add("fade-in")
const remove_class_on_scroll = () = \ > header.classList.remove("fade-in")

window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  scrollpos = window.scrollY;

  if (scrollpos\ >= header_height) {
    add_class_on_scroll()
  } else {
    remove_class_on_scroll()
  }
})
```

```css
.navbar {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fcf9f9 d5;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  transition: all 300ms ease;
  height: 120px;
}

.navbar .fade-in {
  opacity: 1;
  position: fixed;
}

.navbar .logo img {
  position: unset;
  height: 100px;
  width: 140px;
  margin-left: 40px;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar nav">
  <div class="logo">
    <a href="#"><img src="img/The_Butcher2-removebg.png" alt="Mesara logo"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="contact">
    <button id="btn-show-phone">Klikni ovde da vidiš broj telefona</button>
    <div id="phone-number" style="display: none;">Broj telefona: <a href="tel:063-84-54-891" class="phone-link">063-84-54-891</a></div>
  </div>
  <ul class="nav-links">
    <li><a href="#">Početna</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Proizvodi</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">O nama</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Kontakt</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

I asked ChatGPT and googled it, and i couldn't find solution of this problem, I'd really grateful if you can help me :)

Comment: this is not valid html

Comment: Can you tell me why?

Comment: it is markdown, not html

Comment: I am new sorry,I haven't captured everything yet about stackof i changed it now ty :)